# Mail not received from rails sendgrid gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I have setup sendgrid addon on heroku in my rails app, every thing is okay
I have checked heroku log as well event "https://sendgrid.com/logs/index" , it shows mail is Delivered but I am not getting email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding what you're seeing with the delivered status - When you see 'Delivered' in regards to a message, what that's basically telling you is that the receiving server accepted the message. This does not necessarily mean that the receiving server placed that message into the inbox of the intended recipient. The 'reason' that you see in your Email Activity, something like '250 2.0.0 OK', is basically the receiving server saying 'Thanks, we'll take it from here' - This can be thought of as Fedex leaving a package meant to be delivered to an apartment with the doorman of the building that contains that apartment. If the doorman looks at the package and says 'Eh I'll get to this later' or 'This seems sketchy - in the trash with you' then that package will never reach the intended recipient and the sender only knows what Fedex tells them which is that the package was signed for and therefore considered delivered. In this case, email is working in a very similar manner - Once the receiving server responds with something like '250 2.0.0 OK' then you really have no insight into what happens to that message unless you get in contact with an admin or postmaster at the recipient domain. It's possible that the receiving server quarantined the message but your best bet would be to contact whomever administrators the receiving mail server and see if they can provide any additional detail. Sometimes the reason that you see in Email Activity will also contain a unique identifying string which can also be helpful in tracking down a message on the recipient server side.